# Is HTTP/2 supported in quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

Does quarkus support HTTP/2 or is it planned in a future release?

For now, I use a reverse proxy with nginx to allow http/2 but it would be nice to have this in quarkus too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: as mentioned by @Ajax, HTTP 2 is supported in Quarkus since 1.4.**

The underlying layers of Quarkus support it but AFAIK it's not exposed and you can't enable it.

We are in the process of rewriting the HTTP layer so now is a good time to open an issue so that we take that into account in the rewrite.~~

Can you open an issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've created the issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3626

Comment: This is no longer true. It is now supported.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-1-4-final-released/